# How to connect local hosted Azure BOT from your web application

Tags: debugging, iis, bots, direct-line-botframework

I have created an BOT with Microsoft BOT Framework and published in local IIS. Now I want to connect that from my web application, So far I found this could be only possible through direct line from azure portal. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to connect that from my web application, So far I found this could be only possible through direct line from azure portal. Is there any other way to do that?

In my opinion, the Microsoft BOT Framework application is just a service which provide the bot endpoint. You could host it in anywhere.

If you want to connect to your web application or something else. You need to use a channel to connect the bot with other application. You should register the bot and enable the channel to let your bot work. The Azure provide multiple chanels to register the bot like webchat.  You could also build the channel by yourself, but you should think about a lot of things.

More details, you could refer to below answer:

[How to connect local hosted Azure BOT from your web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992130/how-to-connect-local-hosted-azure-bot-from-your-web-application)

Comment: Thanks, My question is why I need to register BOT? I published my BOT in local IIS now I want to connect that BOT in my local web application. Yes I did that, register BOT with Azure, create a direct line channel and link through webChat from my web application, But I want to do that locally. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: As I say, if you don't want to register azure webchat channel, you should write your own service like a channel to link your application and bot application. You could build your own channel service by yourself.You could directly send the request to the bot endpoint and show the response in your web application. Notice: The bot endpoint just receive active format request, you should convert it firstly in your client application.